# EXTJS HTML editor component

Tags: extjs

I am running into a issue where i want to change the html font color to red instead of default black color without using the enable properties.

Is there any way we can override the style properties of text color in editor's text area.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize htmleditor with custom style

```
var htmlEditor = Ext.create('Ext.form.HtmlEditor', {
    listeners: {
        initialize: function(editor) {
            var styles = {
                "color": "red"
            };
            Ext.DomHelper.applyStyles(editor.getEditorBody(), styles);
        }
    }
});
```

---

**[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/erb)**